# Flask/SQLAlchemy - error creating models with one to many relationship (One or more mappers failed to initialize...)

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to make one to many relationship between these 2 tables ("users" and "planets") but am getting this error:

One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class User->users'. Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.planet - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

I have seen answers to this question but none of them worked, I don't know where is the problem?

I also want to separate the 2 models in 2 different files, how that gonna work in this case?

Thanks so much for your help.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, FLOAT
from app import db, ma


# database models:
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
    email = Column(String, unique=True)
    password = Column(String)

    planet = db.relationship('Planet', backref='users', lazy='dynamic')


class Planet(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'planets'
    planet_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    planet_name = Column(String)
    planet_type = Column(String)
    home_star = Column(String)
    mass = Column(FLOAT)
    radius = Column(FLOAT)
    distance = Column(FLOAT)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')


class PlanetSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('planet_id', 'planet_name', 'planet_type', 'home_star', 'mass', 'radius', 'distance')
```

**#__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager, jwt_required, create_access_token
# from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

db = SQLAlchemy()
ma = Marshmallow()
jwt = JWTManager()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'planets.db')
    app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY']='super_secret'   
    # cors = CORS(app)
    # app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

    db.init_app(app)
    ma.init_app(app)
    jwt.init_app(app)
    # jwt = JWTManager(app)

    from views import planet, users
    app.register_blueprint(planet.main)
    app.register_blueprint(users.users)

    return app
```

Comment: This is potentially as simple as you have defined the foreign key on `planets.user_id` back to `user.id`, but the table is called `users`, plural, not `user` singular. I say potentially as once I noticed that, I stopped reading so let me know if that helps.

Comment: @SuperShoot I changed the ForeignKey to "users.id" and am getting this error: no such column: planets.user_id